# display this minimum order amount in magento front end

Tags: magento

I created a shipping rule in magento to enable shipping charges for all purchases below x amount.Is there any possible way to display this minimum order amount in magento front end dynamically?

what i want to do is to use this value to create a condition.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1):

Create a static block and write price. Then call this static block wherever you want to show your minimum price.

If you want to call this in phtml, use the following code

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('Identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```

For CMS page : `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="identifier"}}`

Comment: thanks Abhinav.. But I had to rebuilt another module so i guess i might be able to covered this functionality in that. Anyways thanks for your help...